# Date format identification

Tags: c#, .net, date, format, structured-data

I have come across a date in some structured data that is formatted in a way I'm not familiar with:

```
2021-05-22AEST21:29:32+10:00
```

What's this **format called**?

I'm familiar with "normal" ISO formatted dates, like `2021-05-22T21:29:32-05:00` (which is what the google structured data testing tool converts this date to). Clearly the format is date, timezone, time, offset.

I need to be able to read and *verify dates formatted in this way*. Google knows how to read this and I've come across the in structured data of various sites, but I'm unsure of the name of the format so I'm struggling to research the possible variation.

The variations I've come across so far are:

```
2020-08-25GMT+000008:22:57+00:00
2021-05-22AEST21:29:32+10:00
2016-11-11AEDT15:44:20+11:00
```

**Edit for clarity:**
I know what the individual components are: Date, timezone, time, offset. I need to know what the overall format is called.

Comment: the last part after + sign indicates offset, hence research `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: @Dimitry Bychenko, the question is about the format where `YYYY-MM-DD'**T**':..` seems to be replaced with `YYYY-MM-DD'**TZD**':..`

Comment: I'm aware of what GMT, AEST and AEDT represent. I need to know the name of the overall format. @SnowGroomer is correct - the question's about the overall format.

Comment: Honestly, to me this looks like a mistake, especially given how the tzd is concatenated with hours. I don't believe any sane person would make this a real format. Fortunately, this should be quite straightforward to parse.

Comment: @SnowGroomer I agree - I was just hoping that someone would be able to say "Oh, that's RFC12345XYZ format", but it's not looking like that's the case. I don't think I'm going to have issues parsing but it'd just be really helpful to know the specification.